# powershell run as with credential pass as secure string

Tags: powershell

I normally log in as an unprivileged user and elevate processes as a different user that has admin rights. That user password changes daily. I am trying to store that as a secure string in PowerShell and then read it into a credential object and launch processes. It's giving me the error that *the data area passed to a system call is too small*.

Each day to set the password I run:

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file c:\creds\mycached.txt
```

Then, in my .ps1 scripts, I want to elevate using that credential. This is what I'm doing:

```
$proc_fullpath  = "C:\process_tools\Procmon.exe"
$username       = "mydomain\my_admin_userid"
$password       = cat c:\creds\mycached.txt

$cred            = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

$args = "Start-Process " + $proc_fullpath + " -Verb runAs"
# Write-Host $args

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $args
```

I get the following error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

How can I make this work executing a single .exe file (procmon.exe in this case) and when I want to run an .exe that takes parameters?

I know this is basic, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What scares me is the complete lack of security there... SecureString not really being very secure, a text file... but you could always look at the cryptography classes for that... RSA perhaps... And if it were me I have quite enjoyed CPAU for escalating processes outside of the current user's scope http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/

Comment: [Just as a tip, you might find this easier than doing the securestring conversion yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35582168/3905079). No idea about the particular error you're getting with `Start-Process` though.

Comment: @AustinFrench what's the most secure place/method to cache a credential that expires daily so that subsequent PowerShell scripts can utilize the credential during the day without having to re-enter the password each time and re-create the credential?

Comment: @Caveatrob in the link in my comment, the method I use stores the password encrypted (along with the user name, unencrypted), and allows for very easy retrieval.

Comment: `(Get-Credential).Password` is still a System.SecureString. only encrypted in the lightest sense of the word...

Comment: Although SecureString ***IS*** generally good enough, it may not be in this case.

Comment: @AustinFrench in what way is a securestring "encrypted in the lightest sense of the word"?